# HTML5 canvas library with support for both percentage-based and fixed unit coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm looking for a 2D HTML5 canvas library which allows me to specify coordinates like:

```
X: 5% + 5px
Y: 50% - 20px
```

Of course that doesn't mean they should support that specific notation, as long as they allow for the same logic. For instance:

```
{
  xPercent: 5,
  xFixed: 5,
  yPercent: 50,
  yFixed: -20
}
```

Would be fine.

There are quite a few nice HTML5 canvas libraries out there, which allow for DOM-like manipulation of entities (circles, rectangles, images, etc) inside the canvas, animations and interactivity. So far I looked at [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/), [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) and [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS).

**The problem is:**

As far as I know, these don't allow for coordinates to be specified in both percentage and fixed unit format **(at the same time, as in the example above)**.

Up to this point, I haven't found any canvas library which supports this. My next step would be to implement a wrapper over an existing 2D canvas library. On each window resize, this wrapper transforms the coordinates from the percentage + fixed format into pixels and passes them down to the canvas library.

To me it seems like a common problem when implementing responsive canvas applications, so I'm interested to know how others have tackled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I built a custom solution for this and made it available on [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/object-canvas).

It supports simple shapes (lines, boxes, circles), text and hover/click events.

A demo is available [here](http://rawgit.com/timeinvariant/object-canvas/master/dist/demo/index.html).